# MySQL: Count rows based on fields name

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySql db table structure is:

```
id | status
1  |  Open
2  |  Open
3  |  Closed
4  |  Open
5  |  Closed
```

and i want to count total number of Open and Closed rows.

```
Status | Total
Open   |   3
Closed |   2
```

I used

```
SELECT count(distinct status) as Total FROM my_tbl
```

but it returns

```
Total
  2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT status,
COUNT(id) AS `total`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY status
ORDER BY total DESC
```